# Form Submitting on input change, but does not log onsubmit event. How to check if input submitted or not?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form that submits on input change. I have added an onsubmit event on form to log, if submit happens. But it does not log my submit.

Here is my code:

```
<label for="id_cover_picture">Upload Cover</label>
<form action="" method="get" id="change_cover_picture_form">
    <input type="file" name="cover_pic" id="id_cover_picture" style="display: none;">
</form>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
    <script>
        const change_cover_picture_form = document.getElementById('change_cover_picture_form');
        const form_cover_img = document.getElementById('id_cover_picture');

        form_cover_img.addEventListener('input', () => {
            console.log('input changed ...');
            // even if it reloads , there will be data on localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('input_change', 'input change ... cover image')
            change_cover_picture_form.submit();
        })

        change_cover_picture_form.onsubmit = () => {
            console.log('Form submitted ...');
            // even if it reloads , there will be data on localStorage
            localStorage.setItem('submit_cover', 'submitted ... cover image')
        }
    </script>
```

I am logging the input change and submitting the form, but not logging the submit...

Please correct me, how to confirm submit, and why the onsubmit is not working.
I have even tried with, `addEventListener('submit')`

Expected Answer:

Log the submit, and perform some action if submit happens

Comment: How are you submitting the form without a submit button?

Comment: The form is being submiited with JavaScript on input chnage, @Run_Script

Comment: Nothing to do with the issue, but having the label outside the form is certainly unusual.

Comment: Typically the browser will clear the console when the page refreshes, and the page will refresh, since the empty `action` will cause it to GET the current URL. Are you checking local storage for the entry you're setting?

Comment: Note that typically one does not send images over a GET request, but that's how your form is set up. That could also be causing issues.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I need a button that triggers file input type and allows to select some file from computer, so even if I have a label outside the it will exactly work the same, whats the deal? AND i am just using the get method to check the url after submit, I will chnage it to POST. I am using the localStorage to happen something (i.e. to store some data) because the log can get cleared after the page reloads on submit.

Comment: As I said, it's unusual. That's all.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Yes, it's unusual, but nothing to do with the code I guess. I checked the form is submitting, but what happens after is not usual. :p. It will be good if you look into that problem.

Comment: My comment about the label outside the form started off with the words "Nothing to do with the issue". Not sure how much clearer I can be...

Comment: I also asked if you checked local storage for the entry you added, not why you're using local storage. If the local storage entry is added, then the onsubmit is working as intended.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Yes, I checked. It only logs the input change, but not the submit.

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to submit the form. Add a submit input to the form and then click that.

Comment: The form is being submitted on input change with JavaScript.